# Users tagged in image (Twitter API)

Tags: twitter, tweets, rtweet

Using Twitter API, is there any way to find out which users are tagged in an image attached to a Tweet?

For instance, [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/ObserveIR/status/1412298798978768899)'s accompanying media has 10 users tagged (see the red circle):

[image: A Tweet with 10 users marked in the accompanying media]

I use R's `rtweet`-package.

My use of `rtweet::get_timeline("ObserveIR", n = 15, token = my_token)` leads to 90 variables per Tweet (showing the 15 latest Tweets of that user), but none of the variables shows the desired output.